# c++ why "A a();" will not call constructor

Tags: c++11

Why A a(); won't call constructor?
and why sizeof(C) is 1?

```
class C
{
public:
    C(){ 
        cout << "C default" << endl; 
    }
};

int main() {
    C a();
    cout << sizeof(C) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

does “C a();” become a function Statement？

Comment: [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: What `A`? I only see `C`.

Answer (score 5):

```
C a();
```

That doesn't create an instance of `C` called `a`, that declares a function called `a` which takes no arguments and returns a `C`.

To get what you want you have two main options:

```
C a;
C a{}; //c++11
```

`sizeof(C)` is `1` because *every* object in C++ takes up at least one byte, even if nothing meaningful is stored there. Think about if you had an array of `C`; if `sizeof(C)` was `0`, `c_array[0]` would be at the same address as `c_array[10]`. C++ doesn't allow two distinct objects to have the same address.

Answer (score -1):

1.If you want to call the constructor when a new object be created,
The code should like this:

C a;

C *a = new C();

2.Because no object shall have the same address in memory as any other variable.

So if the class or struct has no variables or functions, sizeof(class) = 1.

Comment: For No. 2, he's asking *why* it has size of `1` when there are no member variables. Not whether it does.

Comment: yeah, I will edit it